# Schneide ich mich oder mir in den Finger?

Tags: grammatical-case, reflexive

Ich war gerade am Kochen (in der Küche, nicht vor Wut), und hätte beinahe in meinen Finger geschnitten. Und da kam mir die Frage:

> Habe ich ***mich*** beinahe in den Finger geschnitten?

oder

> Habe ich ***mir*** beinahe in den Finger geschnitten?

Was ist offiziell und was ist (wo) gebräuchlich?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schneiden) sagt zum Verb schneiden klar: Beides ist korrekt.:

> Beispiele: du schnittst; du schnittest; ich habe mir, auch mich in den Finger geschnitten; schneid[e]!

Die Erklärung liegt (mMn) in den Grundsätzen von reflexiven Verben: Ein reflexives Verb kann sowohl den Dativ als auch den Akkusativ nach sich ziehen, wie in [diesem Link](http://mein-deutschbuch.de/reflexive-verben.html) beschrieben wird.

Laut dem Artikel: Bezieht sich das Verb auf das Subjekt des Satzes, dann steht das Reflexivpronomen im Akkusativ (Ich schneide **mich**), nimmt also die Stelle einer Akkusativ- Ergänzung ein. Bezieht es sich auf eine bestehende Akkusativ- Ergänzung, dann steht es selbst im Dativ (Ich schneide **mir** in den Finger).

Das heisst: Wenn Du betonen möchtest, dass Du dich geschnitten hast, dann würdest Du **dich** schreiben, wenn es Dir wichtig ist, dass es Dein Finger war, den Du erwischt hast, dann schreibst Du **dir**

Comment: Danke für deinen Link, ich glaube aber, deine Interpretation ist nicht richtig, bitte studiere den Abschnitt: Reflexivpronomen mit Dativ oder mit Akkusativ. Das ist eine Akkusativ-Ergänzung der der Dativ zu folgen hat.

Comment: Sorry.. Du hast recht, das hatte ich durcheinander geschmissen... habe es korrigiert.

Comment: Nur dass *in den Finger* keine Akkusativergänzung ist, sondern eine Präpositionalergänzung.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt beide Möglichkeiten:

> Ich habe mir in den Finger geschnitten.
>   Ich habe mich in den Finger geschnitten.

Fragen: Wem hast du in den Finger geschnitten? Antwort: Mir. (Das ist der **Dativ**.) Wen hast du in den Finger geschnitten? Antwort: Mich. (Das ist der **Akkusativ**.) "in den Finger" ist hier eine Direktiv-Ergänzung, die den Ort näher spezifiziert und keinen speziellen Fall für das Reflexivpronom verlangt.

Dagegen:

> Ich habe mich geschnitten.

Frage: **Wen oder was** hast du geschnitten? Antwort: Mich. (Das ist der **Akkusativ**.) Es gibt keine Ergänzung, das Relfexivpronom steht immer im Akkusativ.

Es gibt nun reflexive Verben im Deutschen, die eine Akkusativ-Ergänzung verlangen, dann folgt der Dativ:

> Ich merke mir das Gedicht.

Comment: Ich kann aber auch fragen: **Wen** hast du in den Finger geschnitten? Ich habe **mich** in den Finger geschnitten. Ob ich den Teil »in den Finger« weglasse oder hinzunehme, ist egal.

Comment: @Hubert Leider nicht, der Finger ist hier entscheidend, da dieser schon im Akkusativ steht. Es ist ein Akkusativobjekt, das den Dativ des Reflexivpronomen verlangt.

Comment: Der Teil »in den Finger« ist **keine** Akkusativergänzung ist. »Eine Kerbe« wäre eine Akkusativergänzung. Es kann nur »Ich schneide *mir* eine Kerbe« heißen, nicht aber »Ich schneide *mich* eine Kerbe«. In diesem Fall hättest du recht. Aber nach »in den Finger« kann man nicht mit »*wen oder was*« fragen, sondern nur mit »*wohin*«. Und die Antwort auf eine wohin-Frage enthält zusätzlich zum Akkusativ auch immer eine lokale Präposition. So ein Gebilde ist **keine** Akkusativ-Ergänzung, sondern eine **Direktiv-Ergänzung** http://mein-deutschbuch.de/direktiv-ergaenzung.html.

Comment: Ah, danke, die Präposition macht also den Unterschied.

Comment: @Hubert, tut mir leid, aber das Thema lässt mir keine Ruhe, "in den Finger" wegzulassen ist eben doch nicht egal und hat durchaus Einfluss, es wäre falsch: "Ich habe mir geschnitten." Ich gebe zu meine Interpretation der Regel war am Anfang falsch und zu einfach, ich versuche das gleich in der Antwort zu korrigieren.

Answer (score 2):

Analysieren wir mal die beiden Sätze aus Sicht des Verbs:

> Ich schneide mich in den Finger.

- **Ich** – Nominativergänzung (wer?)
- **schneide** – reflexives Verb mit drei Ergänzungen
- **mich** – reflexive Akkusativergänzung (wen?)
- **in den Finger** – Direktivergänzung (wohin?)

Dieser Satz entspricht vom Satzbau her genau den folgenden Beispielen:

> Hannes sehnt sich nach Hause zurück.
>   Du bringst dich in Teufels Küche.
>   Wir bewegen uns nach Süden.

Das ist ein gängiger Satzbau und somit anscheinend vollkommen korrekt.
(Beachte meinen Nachtrag weiter unten, der diese Aussage wieder relativiert.)

---

Nun das andere Beispiel:

> Ich schneide mir in den Finger.

- **Ich** – Nominativergänzung (wer?)
- **schneide** – reflexives Verb mit drei Ergänzungen
- **mir** – reflexive Dativergänzung (wem?)
- **in den Finger** – Direktivergänzung (wohin?)

Man könnte die Direktivergänzung als besondere Form einer Akkusativergänzung sehen. Immerhin steht der Finger im Akkusativ. Eine echte Akkusativergänzung enthält aber keine lokale Präposition. Außerdem wird nach einer Akkusativergänzung mit »wen oder was« gefragt, nicht mit »wohin«.

Eine echte Akkusativergänzung wäre »eine Kerbe«, »eine Wunde«, »ein Muster« oder etwas Ähnliches. Das sind Sätze, die eine Dativ- und eine Akkusativ-Ergänzung enthalten:

> Ich schneide mir eine Kerbe.
>   Ich schneide mir eine Wunde.
>   Ich schneide mir ein Muster.

Die Ergänzung kommt ganz ohne lokale Präposition (*in*, *auf*, *durch* usw.) aus und kann mit »*wen oder was*« erfragt werden.

Hier gilt die Regel:

> Wenn an ein Verb zusätzlich zu einer Nominativ- und einer Akkusativ-Ergänzung auch noch eine dritte Ergänzung gebunden ist, muss diese Ergänzung im Dativ (und vor der Akkusativergänzung) stehen.

Das ist auch in den folgenden Beispielen der Fall:

> Ich überlasse *dir* meinen Mantel.
>   Doris schenkt *ihrem Vater* einen Hut.
>   Ich gönne *mir* ein Bier.

### Aber:

Eine Direktivergänzung ist nunmal keine Akkusativergänzung, auch wenn sie außer einer Präposition auch noch einen Akkusativausdruck enthält. Daher greift die obige Regel nicht.

Das heißt aber trotzdem nicht, dass nun das Gegenteil gelten würde, dass also der Dativ verboten wäre.

Tatsächlich habe ich nirgendwo eine Regel gefunden, die irgendeine Aussage über *Dativergänzung plus Direktivergänzung* macht. Weder pro noch kontra.

Nachdem es keine (festgeschriebene) Regel gibt, zählt nur der tatsächliche Gebrauch, und hier kann man feststellen, dass der Satz

> Ich schneide mir in den Finger.

tatsächlich verwendet wird und daher nicht falsch ist.

---

### Fazit:

Beide Sätze sind richtig.

---

### Nachtrag

Nochmal zurück zum Akkusativ, den ich am Beginn analysiert habe:

Die oben genannten Beispielsätze haben ein Problem: »Bringen«, »schneiden« und - in Form eines Wunsches auch - »sehnen« sind Verben, die eine Ortsveränderung des ganzen Subjekts ausdrücken. Es geht dabei im weitesten Sinn um eine Reise.

Das ist bei »schneiden« aber nicht der Fall. Hierbei geht es um eine Bewegung, die von einer Person, die im Subjekt steht, initiiert wird, und die dazu führt, dass etwas in einen Teil des Körpers der auslösenden Person eindringt.

Ein solches Beispiel ist:

> Ich schieße *mir/mich* ins Knie.

In diesem Fall scheint mir nur der Dativ (also »mir«) richtig zu sein.

Für den Inhalt des folgenden Beispiels entschuldige ich mich schon mal in Voraus, aber es ist ein Beispiel, das exakt demselben Bauplan folgt, bei dem ich aber glaube, dass hier nur der Akkusativ richtig ist:

> Du fickst *dir/dich* in den Allerwertesten.

Wie gesagt halte ich hier den Dativ für falsch und glaube, das hier nur der Akkusativ (also »dich«) richtig ist.

Somit stellen der Satz mit den Knieschuss und der Satz mit dem F-Wort zwei Beispiele mit genau demselben Satzbau aber unterschiedlichen grammatischen Fällen für die reflexive Ergänzung dar. Ich glaube, dass der Satz mit dem Fingerschnitt irgendwo dazwischen anzusiedeln ist. und bleibe daher bei meinem Fazit, dass nämlich beide Versionen korrekt sind.

Comment: Wenn ich es mir mal so bewusst vorlese ... "Ich schneide mich." ist ok. "Ich schneide mich in den Finger." klingt irgendwie nicht richtig. Auch die Vergleichs-Sätze passen nicht; bei allen Beispielen bewege ich mich als ganzes. Gibt es ein weiteres Beispiel, bei dem ich "mich" benutze, das aber direkt im Anschluss auf einen Teil von mir beschränke? "Ich habe mich das Gesicht gewaschen." ... neeee!

Comment: @Titus: Das mit dem Bewegen als Ganzes ist mir einige Stunden nachdem ich den Beitrag gepostet habe, auch aufgefallen. »Schneiden« ist kein Verb, das eine Bewegung eines Ganzen von A nach B ausdrückt. »Bringen«, »bewegen« und - im übertragenen Sinn - »sehnen« aber sehrwohl. Dein Gegenbeispiel mit dem Gesichtwaschen passt aber auch nicht. »Das Gesicht« ist eine astreine Akkusativergänzung, »in den Finger« ist aber eine Direktivergänzung. Was passen würde wäre »Ich schieße mi? ins Knie.«

Comment: (Forts.:)  Es muss ganz allgemein um etwas gehen, bei dem man selbst eine Bewegung veranlasst, die dazu führt, dass etwas in einen Teil des eigenen Körpers eindringt. Außer dem Schuss ins eigene Knie fallen mir nur Beispielsätze ein, die in einen Pornoroman passen würden. Während ich beim Knieschuss für »mir« plädieren würde, scheint mir hingegen bei »Ich ficke mi? in den Arsch« aber »mich« besser zu passen. (Sorry für das Beispiel, mir fällt kein besseres ein.)

Comment: "Fick Dich ins Knie" fällt mir jetzt ein ... als Beispiel, nicht als Kommentar. Richtig ist das ja, aber scheint ja auch korrekt zu sein.

Answer (score 1):

Die "richtigen" Fälle werden manchmal deutlicher, wenn man die Bezüge ändert:

> Ich habe mich geschnitten. - **nicht:** *Ich habe mir geschnitten.*
>   Ich habe mir den Finger abgeschnitten. - **nicht:** *Ich habe mich den Finger abgeschnitten.*
>   Ich habe dir in das Hemd geschnitten - **nicht:** *Ich habe dich in das Hemd geschnitten*

Allerdings ist *ich habe mich in den Finger geschnitten* dermaßen häufig, dass man es als korrekt werten kann (Regeln folgen dem Gebrauch!).

Answer (score 1):

Beide Varianten sind richtig, setzen aber unterschiedliche Bezüge.

> Ich habe mich (in den Finger) geschnitten.

Der primäre Bezug ist, dass ich *mich* geschnitten habe; die dazugehörige Frage ist »Wen hast du geschnitten?« Durch die Ortsangabe (wohin?) wird klar, *wo* der Schnitt am Ende auftaucht. Möglich wäre theoretisch auch:

> Ich habe mich im Finger geschnitten.

Wobei dann allerdings die Frage erlaubt sein muss, wie man ohne Schnitt in seinen eigenen Finger gekommen ist.

> Ich habe mir in den Finger geschnitten.

Auch hier erscheint *in den Finger* wie eine Ortsangabe, doch in diesem Satz erfüllt es die Funktion eines Präpositionalobjektes und kann nicht entfernt werden. Ohne *in den Finger* ist der Satz höchstens noch im Berliner Dialekt oder verwandten Dialekten, in denen *mich* konsequent in allen Fällen durch *mir* ersetzt wird, gestattet:

> Ick hab mir jeschnitten.
>
> <del>Ich habe mir geschnitten.</del>

Erst in Folge dessen kommt das Reflexivpronomen *mir* hinzu, welches beschreibt, *wem* ich in den Finger geschnitten habe.